# Flutter AlarmManager not working with flutter_nearby_connections plugin says: PlatformException lateinit property activity has not been initialized,

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin, dart

I am calling flutter nearby connection plugin code in background service call back function so I can detect nearby devices in background it does not work because nearby connection plugin of flutter requires context of activity. How to provide that in call back? If I am calling nearbyconnection constructor in callback of background service it says activity is `null`. If I am calling nearby devices code from background function of any flutter plugin like `background_fetch` or `alarm_manager` it does not work it says kotlin property activity is not initialized in `flutter_nearby_connections` plugin. But I have to call that code in background how can I give activity context from flutter code of callback? Without background service nearby devices is working perfectly fine but when using it with background function it doesn't work saying activity is `null`. How to resolve this?

```
import 'dart:isolate';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:android_alarm_manager_plus/android_alarm_manager_plus.dart';
import 'package:flutter_nearby_connections/flutter_nearby_connections.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  bool test = await AndroidAlarmManager.initialize();
  runApp(NearbyPlease());
}

class NearbyPlease extends StatefulWidget {
  const NearbyPlease({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _NearbyPleaseState createState() => _NearbyPleaseState();
}

class _NearbyPleaseState extends State<NearbyPlease> {
  NearbyService nearbyService = NearbyService();
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(body: Center(child: RaisedButton(onPressed: () async {
      //this function nearbydevice will run after every one minute in background even
      // the app is closed
      await AndroidAlarmManager.periodic(
          const Duration(seconds: 60), 101, printHello);
    }))));
  }

  static Future<void> printHello() async {
    try {
      NearbyService nearbyService = NearbyService();
      await nearbyService.init(
          callback: (running) async {
            nearbyService.startAdvertisingPeer();
            await nearbyService.startBrowsingForPeers();
          },
          serviceType: 'mpconn',
          strategy: Strategy.P2P_CLUSTER,
          deviceName: Random().nextInt(9).toString());
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

pubspec.yaml

```
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  android_alarm_manager_plus: ^1.0.1
  flutter_nearby_connections:



dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true
```

Error logs:

```
Syncing files to device CPH1937...
I/e.alarm_manage(16947): ProcessProfilingInfo new_methods=431 is saved saved_to_disk=1 resolve_classes_delay=5000
I/FlutterBackgroundExecutor(16947): Starting AlarmService...
I/AndroidAlarmManagerPlugin(16947): onAttachedToEngine
I/AlarmService(16947): AlarmService started!
D/SurfaceView(16947): 27843277 setAlpha: mUseAlpha = false alpha=1.0
D/SurfaceView(16947): 27843277 updateSurfaceAlpha: setUseAlpha() is not called, ignored.
D/ColorViewRootUtil(16947): swipeFromBottom!
D/ColorViewRootUtil(16947): nav bar mode ignore false downX 370 downY 794 mScreenHeight 1600 mScreenWidth 720 mStatusBarHeight 36 globalScale 1.125 nav mode 0 rotation 0 event MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=370.0, y[0]=794.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, classification=NONE, metaState=0, flags=0x2, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=12896264, downTime=12896264, deviceId=5, source=0x1002, displayId=0 }
D/ColorViewRootUtil(16947): swipeFromBottom!
D/ColorViewRootUtil(16947): swipeFromBottom!
E/MethodChannel#flutter_nearby_connections(16947): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#flutter_nearby_connections(16947): kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property activity has not been initialized
E/MethodChannel#flutter_nearby_connections(16947):  at com.nankai.flutter_nearby_connections.FlutterNearbyConnectionsPlugin.onMethodCall(FlutterNearbyConnectionsPlugin.kt:77)
E/MethodChannel#flutter_nearby_connections(16947):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
E/MethodChannel#flutter_nearby_connections(16947):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
E/MethodChannel#flutter_nearby_connections(16947):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:818)
E/MethodChannel#flutter_nearby_connections(16947):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#flutter_nearby_connections(16947):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:336)
E/MethodChannel#flutter_nearby_connections(16947):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:184)
E/MethodChannel#flutter_nearby_connections(16947):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7864)
E/MethodChannel#flutter_nearby_connections(16947):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#flutter_nearby_connections(16947):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
E/MethodChannel#flutter_nearby_connections(16947):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:998)
E/flutter (16947): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, lateinit property activity has not been initialized, null, kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property activity has not been initialized
E/flutter (16947):  at com.nankai.flutter_nearby_connections.FlutterNearbyConnectionsPlugin.onMethodCall(FlutterNearbyConnectionsPlugin.kt:77)
E/flutter (16947):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
E/flutter (16947):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
E/flutter (16947):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:818)
E/flutter (16947):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/flutter (16947):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:336)
E/flutter (16947):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:184)
E/flutter (16947):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7864)
E/flutter (16947):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/flutter (16947):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
E/flutter (16947):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:998)
E/flutter (16947): )
E/flutter (16947): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:597:7)
E/flutter (16947): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:158:18)
E/flutter (16947): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Anyone knows how to resolve this so I can detect nearby devices in background?I have tried same code with `foreground_service` flutter plugin and `background_fetch` plugin of flutter but getting same exception.